# How do i log the user's name to console?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I'm making a Discord bot for a server and I am having trouble with this. I want it to log the user's name to console. So far it looks like:
`INFO: <#777176816950575114> started typing in a channel`
I tried changing it to `user.tag` instead of `user.name` but that changed the numerical id to `undefined`. Any ideas?

```
client.on('typingStart', user => {
    console.log(`${chalk.bold.blue("INFO")}${chalk.blue(`: ${user.name} started typing in a channel`)}`);
})
```

**EDIT:** I have had the suggestions `user.user.tag` and `user.username`. These aren't working: `user.user.tag` returns an error and `user.username` returns undefined.

Comment: It's `user.username` or `user.user.tag`

Comment: @Lioness100 that didn't work, user.user.tag gave an error & user.username returns undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this](https://gist.github.com/koad/316b265a91d933fd1b62dddfcc3ff584) example. Channel is the first parameter and user is the second parameter.

```
client.on('typingStart', (channel, user) => {
    console.log(`${chalk.bold.blue("INFO")}${chalk.blue(`: ${user.username} started typing in a channel`)}`);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use user.username to get the username of a person.
console.log(user.username);